# Why can't I 'enter' the Omega 4 relay?

Tags: mass-effect-2

The 'enter' button is not shown. I have completed all the missions I can find, including obtaining the IFF. Is there anything else I need to do to 'enter' the Omega 4 relay?  What have I missed ??

Comment: Has the IFF been installed and tested yet? This happens shortly after all plot missions are completed and results in a major event occurring. You'd know if it had happened.

Comment: The ship got boarded, and some of my crew are dead, but I don't recall being told that the IFF installation/test was complete.

Comment: Then yes, you are past the event.  If memory serves, you don't access the relay, you access the endpoint from the galaxy map.  You also have time to run one more mission (ostensibly the loyalty mission for your final squad mate).

Comment: Thanks. I am in the Galaxy map, and can see the relay.  When I fly over it, I am offered the opportunity to 'Enter Orbit'.  When I do that, the relay is full-screen, with the description of it in a box on the right hand side.  There is a 'back' button, but nothing else to click on to commit.

Comment: Have you completed at least 5 loyalty/side missions since getting all your dossier squaddies? That could be doing it.

Comment: Thanks jordie3000, yes, I can find no more missions to complete.  Maybe I should just go back to near the beginning and run it through again ?